# How to get the day number in a month in c#

Tags: c#, numbers

How to get all dates for particular weekdays in certain year for example:

```
Monday : 07.01.2015,14.01.2015,...,21.02.2015, ,28.12.2015
Tuesday : 08.01.2015, 15.01.2015,..., 22.02.2015, 29.12.2015
```

etc ...

thanks

Comment: So show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: This is very good question, why 7 down votes?

Comment: @X-TECH I see why downvoting as no self-approach as been done, but I don´t know why closing.

Comment: I think this is not easy for beginners. So, he may not try in such a way to show his code.

Comment: @X-TECH First comment has been posted 30minutes ago, so enough time to react accordinlgy I think.

Comment: i forget to put my try sorry, i was trying to do it with the calendar object !

Comment: Sure you did, a bit more detail? Some code you already tried? Prefereably in your question instead of within the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DaysInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dow)
{ 
    DateTime monthStart = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
        .Select(day => monthStart.AddDays(day))
        .Where(date => date.DayOfWeek == dow)
        .Select(date => date.Day);
}
```

Your example:

```
var wednesdaysInSeptember2015 = DaysInMonth(2015, 9, DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
Console.Write(String.Join(",", wednesdaysInSeptember2015)); // 2,9,16,23,30
```

---

For what it's worth, here is a performance optimized version:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DaysInMonthMicroOptimized(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    DateTime monthStart = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    int distanceToDayOfWeek = (dayOfWeek < monthStart.DayOfWeek ? 7 : 0) + dayOfWeek - monthStart.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime dayOfWeekInMonth = monthStart.AddDays(distanceToDayOfWeek);
    yield return dayOfWeekInMonth.Day;
    while((dayOfWeekInMonth = dayOfWeekInMonth.AddDays(7)).Month == month)
        yield return dayOfWeekInMonth.Day;
}
```

Comment: Once you have the first day you can just add 7 until you reach the end of month. There's probably a way to find the first day without iterating either - eg find the week day of the first month day, add/subtract the target day of week, etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: i try to provide the easiest/most readable version first. Since you enumerate 31 days at a maximum this should not be a performance problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: added an optimized version for you ;)