# Get Saturdays of a Month

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the day number of Saturdays of each month.

For example, this month (August) should return: 4, 11, 18, 28

```
int year = 2018;
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
DateTime myDT = new DateTime(year, month, 1, new GregorianCalendar());
Calendar myCal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;

while (myDT.Month == month)
{
    var day = myCal.GetDayOfWeek(myDT);

    if (day == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        Debug.WriteLine(myCal.GetDayOfMonth(myDT));

    myDT.AddDays(1);
}
```

Once I click the button that executes the code, my UI is frozen with no errors returned. This leads me to believe it's still inside the loop for some reason.

Comment: It's my third actually but no worries

Comment: Well your third is far better than mine!

Comment: @EJoshuaS No worries, I got to test out the new flag option anyway :)

Comment: Why 4, 11, 15, 28? Did you mean 4, 11, 18, 25?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller Yes, my bad. edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the day number in a month in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398141/how-to-get-the-day-number-in-a-month-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning it so it maybe be in an eternal loop:

Instead of this:

```
myDT.AddDays(1);
```

Do this:

```
myDT = myDT.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: I think most people call it an infinite loop, but eternal works too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    const int year = 2018;
    int month = DateTime.Now.Month;

    Calendar myCal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
    DayOfWeek[] accepted = new [] { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Friday };

    IEnumerable<DateTime> dateTimes = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)) 
        .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
        .Where(d => accepted.Contains(myCal.GetDayOfWeek(d)));
```